# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on if/else

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   if ('a[href*="mysite.com/"]') {
      jQuery("li#menu-item-4801 a").css("color", "#999");
   } 
   elseif ('a[href*="mysite.com/news"]') {
       jQuery("li#menu-item-4801 a").css("color", "#006aa6");
   }

});
```

But chedked by DevTools, get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `else if` space between else and if

Comment: `elseif` should be `else if`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax error

Comment: It would help a lot if you described what you're trying to do. As it stands, even after you fix the syntax error your code is nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `elseif` in JavaScript. You can follow an `else` statement with another `if` statement, but syntactically that's not quite the same thing. It's close of course.

This `if` statement:

```
if ('a[href*="mysite.com/"]') {
```

will **always** be true. It means, "if the string 'a[href*="mysite.com/"]' is not the empty string, then ...". That string is clearly not the empty string.

Comment: You could be a little more clear, there is no `elseif` but there is an `else if`

Comment: @Constarr yes I extended the answer - it's not exactly the same thing, due to the nesting effect of starting a new `if` statement after an `else`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   if (jQuery('a[href*="mysite.com/"]')) {
      jQuery("li#menu-item-4801 a").css("color", "#999");
   } 
   else if (jQuery('a[href*="mysite.com/news"]')) {
       jQuery("li#menu-item-4801 a").css("color", "#006aa6");
   }

});
```